# How can I get a moving average for each day of the week?

Tags: graphite

I get data into graphite with a granularity of an hour. For example

```
2013-12-06-12:00    15
2013-12-08-09:00    14
2013-12-09-12:00     3
2013-12-13-00:00    10
2013-12-14-08:00    20
2013-12-14-09:00     1
2013-12-15-00:00     5
2013-12-16-00:00    11
2013-12-16-02:00    12
```

... and so on

Now, I'd like to be able to graph this into the "evolution of the value for every day in the week" so the actual value displayed is the sum (or average) of the values for this particular day of week over some weeks (let's say 2 weeks for example).

My graph would look like that if I only look at the last week :

```
  ^       21
20|       |
  |       |
  |   12.5|       13
10|   |   |   9.5 |
  |   |   |   |   |
  |   |   |   |   |
 0+--------------------------------->
   Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
    12  13  14  15  16
```

So for example, for the "Friday" point, it takes the values of today (11+12), the value of last friday (3) and makes an average of both ((11+12)+3)/2

Is this possible, how ?

Comment: I've found that http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.timeShift and that http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.timeStack

Answer (score 5):

`summarize(your.metric.goes.here, "1week", "sum")` will summarize the data in 1 week intervals by summing them. You can [also](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize) use avg, max, min there.

As far as semantics go- Timers, usually need to be averaged and counters need to be summed when summarized.

**Example:** If you measure  `lap-counts` and `lap-times` when you run every day, and want weekly summary, you *average* the `lap-time` of seven days and allocate it to that one weekly `lap-time`. With `lap-count`, it makes more sense to know total, so you *sum* it.

**On a different note:** `timeStack` and `timeShift` are used in cases when you want to *compare* last month's data with this month's on the same timeline. Also, you can *timeShift* the summarized data too.

Answer (score 3):

I think specifically what you are looking for is a combination of both `timeStack` and `averageSeries`. For example:

```
averageSeries(timeStack(your.metric.here,"1week", 0, 2))
```

Where the last two arguments are the range of "1week" series you'd like to incorporate (so it gets a series for this week and each of the previous 2 weeks).